# Feathersjs find request "invalid query parameter" error with reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

When I add `$show:true` to the data (shown below), the find request shows an error.

When I remove `$show:true`, there is no error and working fine.

Error is

> Invalid query parameter $show.

I tried using different `$values` but the server always shows 'invalid parameter $values'

```
data = {$noshow:true,$show:true} ; 
let res = await client.service('servv').find({query:data});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Feathers, query parameters starting with a `$` are treated as special parameters. Often they can be used to make database specific queries (instead of just querying properties) which is why they have to be explicitly allowed on the server in the service configuration (see https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/common.html#options).

Comment: So , icant pass a value as $avalue=true, trough query data of .find() ? , but $noshow is not getting an error ,server only shows error for "$show". If i remone $show from data , the find() will run perfectly.

Comment: That means that it probably has been configured to allow `$noshow`. You just need to add `$show` to the list in the configuration file.

Comment: but i searched for "$noshow" in my entire feathers API. There is literally 2 times "$noshow" written in ther, both in hook.js files (post.hook.js , list.hook.js). couldnt find any config files. Where should i search edit: just searched UI too, nop its only there in action inside redux store, where we call .find({})